# Discord.py - How can I send a message to a discord channel when a youtube video is released?

Tags: youtube, discord.py

I am looking to create a bot that would send a message to a channel when a video is uploaded on the specified channel. I am guessing there must be some sort of api to use, but I don't know which and how. If somebody could help me, that would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need youtube api for it and using backround task check if on that channel is more videos. So I think its better to use some other bot (for example mee6)

Comment: The whole point was I would be able to incorporate the videos into my own bot..

Comment: Ok, i watch it and it is not that hard, just get api key and via this link `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` just get last video from the channel, that video save to json and every 5-10 minutes make background task and check if the video is not the same as in the json, if no, just rewrite the json.